# If an NP problem is shown to have an exponential lower bound, would that prove that P != NP?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, p-vs-np

The *Cook-Levin theorem* shows that any NP problem is reducible to an NP-complete problem.

Therefore if a polynomial-time algorithm for an NP-complete problem is found, it will mean that all problems in NP can be solved in polynomial time.

*But If an NP problem is shown to have an exponential lower bound, would that prove that P != NP?*

Comment: Please do your own homework.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i think now it's better

Comment: Indeed so. The answer to your updated question is within your capabilities. Use the definition of set equality.

Comment: Hint: Look for the definition of NP-hardness.

Comment: You mean a non-polynomial lower bound for (infinitely many instances of) some NP problem. By definition of NP-complete it will lift to any NP-complete problem.

Comment: No, the Cook-Levin theorem says that SAT is **NP**-complete. The fact that every problem in **NP** can be reduced to any **NP**-complete problem _the definition_ of **NP**-completeness.

Comment: Ask yourself this: if a problem has an exponential lower-bound, can it be in **P**? So if there is such a problem that's in **NP**, then... ?